# array.nil? when array having only multiple `nil` values

Tags: arrays, ruby

Consider an array having only one value `nil`

```
array = [nil]
```

Is there any better way to check whether an array is `nil` or not, like `array.nil?`?

This works:

```
array == [nil]
```

But what if there are multiple `nil` values in the array?

```
array = [nil, nil, nil]
```

Below is the requirement:

```
array = [1, 2] if array.nil?
```

`array.nil?` should also give 'true' when `array = [nil, nil, nil]`

Comment: You're trying to see if any elements of `array` are `nil` or if all elements of `array` are `nil`?

Comment: if all elements of array are nil.

Comment: Then I'd go with a modified version of axiac's: `array.all?(&:nil?)`. Says exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Where do the `nil` values come from? What do they indicate?

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? In my opinion the answer given in @muistooshort's comment is best, in part because it reads the best: "All elements of `array`, are `nil`" (which implies, "..or `array` is empty").

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, i will prefer muistooshort's answer given in comment.

Comment: @muistooshort, for good housekeeping, please make that an answer.

Comment: @muistooshort please post your answer below, i was looking for such reduced syntax.

Comment: Another option would be `array.compact.empty?`, but `all?(&:nil?)` is both idiomatic and potentially faster since it would terminate on the first non `nil` value.

Comment: @CarySwoveland _"All elements of array are nil [...] implies array is empty"_ – [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) might not be that obvious.

Comment: As an aside, Ruby 1.9.3 support ended three years ago. Please upgrade for cheap security and performance wins.

Comment: Your question is entirely not clear. What is wrong with `array.nil?`? There is no better way to check if an object is `nil`. Not sure what you mean by "the requirement". You are proposing that `nil?` should behave differently, but that is a request, which you should ask to the Ruby developers. Here is a question site.

Comment: @Stefan, I’d not heard of the term, “vacuous truth”, but it’s a highly useful one. The Wiki article you linked to is interesting.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `all?(&:nil?)` is a minor adjustment to axiac's original answer so I'm happy to have it included in their answer (as it now is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array#any?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-any-3F) to check if the array contains at least one value that is not `false` or `nil`:

```
array = [1,2] unless array.any?
```

If `array` is allowed to contain `false` and you are interested only in `nil` then `Array#any?` needs a block:

```
array = [1,2] unless array.any?{|i| !i.nil?}
```

**Update**

As @mu-is-too-short suggests, a better version is:

```
array = [1,2] if array.all?(&:nil?)
```

It does exactly what you need: [Enumerable#all?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) returns `true` if the block returns a true-ish value for all elements of the array.

Comment: Or `array = [1,2] if array.all?(&:nil?)` to avoid all the negations.

Comment: `all?` was the method I was looking for but it is not listed in the documentation of `Array` and I forgot to check in the documentation of `Enumerable`. Thank you.

Comment: There's also [`none?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-none-3F)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to uniquify your array and then do what you were already doing:

```
array.uniq == [nil]
```

So if `array` is any amount of `nils` it will be true. On the other hand:

```
array.nil?
```

Checks whether array itself is `nil`, which is not the same as an array containing `nil` elements.

Comment: Thanks @kabanus, it worked. Also we can use `array.uniq.first.nil?`

Comment: @Rhunal no, because if you have non-nil elements (`[nil,nil,2]`.uniq -> `[nil,2]`) your test will be invalid.

Comment: yes, right, it will fail if  array having `[2, nil,nil,2]`

Comment: If `array` is empty this returns `false`. That may be OK, but maybe not. The OP has not stated whether `array` could be empty and, if so, what is to be returned when it is empty. Rhunhl?

Comment: @CarySwoveland In my case, I am having `array` which is not empty, it can contain `nil` or any value. Because I am passing `env var` in array, e.g. `[ENV['var']]`. So it will be never empty.

Comment: That's fine, but I think it should be part of the spec given in the question.

Comment: can we reduce the syntax `array == [nil] || array.nil?`?

Comment: @Rhunal if you want to have a default value, you should use something like `[ENV.fetch('var', 1)]`.

Comment: @Rhunal I don't know of anyway - and you're trying to test two different things, so I don't think so - but that syntax is already pretty short and clear - what is your goal here?

Comment: @kabanus when `array` is `empty` or `[nil]` or `nil` , is there any reduced syntax for this? `array == [nil] || array.nil? || array.empty?`

Comment: This is turning into a discussion - I don't know of a way, and please stop asking questions in comments. This also seems like an [xy]. Post a new question if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible ways is to remove `nil` values with [`.compact`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-compact) and check if the result is [`empty?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-empty-3F) .

```
array = [1, 2] if array.compact.empty?
```

Comment: I had added that as a comment below the original post, including a caveat.

Comment: @MichaelKohl Sorry, I didn't notice your comment. You are right about readability and probably right about performance.